# Blend for Visual Studio

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, desktop-application, blend

I want to build a desktop app with C++.
I already built my code using the basic command prompt of visual studio and now want to translate that into a desktop application with a user friendly interface.

I heard I can do that by either coding the interface using Win32 APIs or by using Blend for Visual Studio.
I am more of a UI guy and also not an experienced coder and I think I would go for Blend.
My question is: if I build the app with Blend (2017) is there a way I can make my app run on older versions of Windows? (older than Windows 10)

Comment: Blend is a tool to author XAML. XAML is used with WPF, that can run on systems prior to Windows 10, but you cannot immediately use C++ with WPF. XAML is also used for GUIs in the UWP. While UWP allows you to write C++ code, it requires that you are a rock solid C++ developer. [C++/WinRT](https://aka.ms/cppwinrt) is not for the faint at heart. UWP is available on Windows 10 only.